# Ways of reading txt file contents into forms?

Tags: vb.net, file

At work we have a txt file with items recorded in them

The columns are typical of

```
Apple,  *fruit
Cow,    *animal
House,  *thing
Tree,   *plant
```

Is it possible too read through this txt file to check if apple already exists. I namely want to build a preventative for adding double items...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to read the file in to a list of objects. 
In this case, the object will get 2 properties: Type and Category.

After that you can easily perform comparisons etc on the list itself.

**Edit:** 
Some stuff for you to read;
Reading a file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx

Dictionary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

I'm unable to write down an example now, but those are the ingredients.

Comment: being reletivly new to vb.net do you now any good tutorials or refrences to such?